# How to access pod name/lable in filter section of otel-fargate-container-insights.yaml

Tags: open-telemetry

I followed the instruction in
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-amazon-cloudwatch-container-insights-for-amazon-eks-fargate-using-aws-distro-for-opentelemetry/
I only want to send metrics to CloudWatch for a few pods. I don't know how to access the name/lable of a pod, so I used PodName. I got error. Here is the filter section:

```
 filter:
        metrics:
          include:
            match_type: expr
            expressions:
            - MetricName startsWith "pod_cpu" 
          exclude:
            match_type: expr
            expressions:
            - not (PodName startsWith "abcd")
```

After deployment, I checked the log:

```
 github.com/prometheus/prometheus@v1.8.2-0.20210621150501-ff58416a0b02/scrape/scrape.go:1148
2022-06-16T22:20:35.131Z        error   filterprocessor@v0.39.0/filter_processor.go:127 shouldKeepMetric failed {"kind": "processor", "name": "filter", "error": "cannot fetch PodName from *filterexpr.env (1:6)\n | not (PodName startsWith \"abcd\")\n | .....^"}
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/processor/filterprocessor.(*filterMetricProcessor).processMetrics.func1.1.1
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/processor/filterprocessor@v0.39.0/filter_processor.go:127
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/model/pdata.MetricSlice.RemoveIf
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector/model@v0.39.0/pdata/generated_metrics.go:538
```

Thanks for help in advance,
Julie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/filterprocessor#using-an-expr-match_type

`Podname` is label, so it should be:

```
          exclude:
            match_type: expr
            expressions:
            - not (Label("PodName") startsWith "abcd")
```

Comment: Yes it works, thanks. I need to use pod instead: Label(“pod”)

Comment: @Julie you should to accept answer